# How Blocks gets converted into Records and what exactly is the definition of Record in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am learning Hadoop, and to begin with started with `HDFS` and `MapReduce`. I understood the basics of `HDFS` and `MapReduce`.

There is one particular point where I am not able to understand, which I am explaining below:

Large data set --> Stored in HDFS as Blocks, say for example B1, B2, B3.

Now, when we run a MR Job, each mapper works on a single block (assuming 1 mapper processes a block of data for simplicity)

1 Mapper ==> processes 1 block

I also read that the block is divided into `Records` and for a given block, same mapper is called for each records within that block (of data).

But what exactly is a `Record`?

For a given block, since it has to be "broken" down into `records`, how that block gets broken into records and what constituents a record.

In most of the examples, I have seen a record being a full line delimited by new line.

My doubt is what decides the "conditions" basis on which something can be treated as record.

I know there are many InputFormat in Hadoop, but my question is what are the conditions which decides something to be considered as a record.

Can anyone help me understand this in simple words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of `RecordReader`.

`Block` is a hard bound number of bytes the data is stored on disk. So, by saying a block of 256 MB, means exactly 256 MB piece of data on the disk.
The mapper get 1 record from the block, process it; and get the next one - the onus of defining a record is on `RecordReader`.

Now what is a record? If I provide an analogy of block being a `table`, `record` is a row in the table.
Now think about this - How to process of a block data in mapper, after all you can not write a logic on a random byte of data. From a mapper perspective, you can only have a logic, if the input data "make some sense" or has a structure or a logical chunk of data (from the mapper logic perspective).

That logical chunk is called a `record`. By default one line of data is the logical chunk in the default implementation. But sometime, it does not make sense to have one line of data being a logical data. Sometime, there is no line at all (Say its a MP4 type of data and mapper need one song as input) !

Let's say you have a requirement in mapper which needs to work on 5 consecutive lines together. In that case you need to override the `RecordReader` with an implementation where 5 lines are `one record` and passed together to the mapper.

**EDIT 1**

Your understanding is on right path

> InputFormat: opens the data source and splits the data into chunks
>
> RecordReader: actually parses the chunks into Key/Value pairs.

For the `JavaDoc` of InputFormat

InputFormat describes the input-specification for a Map-Reduce job.
The Map-Reduce framework relies on the InputFormat of the job to:

- Split-up the input file(s) into *logical* InputSplits, each of which is then assigned to an individual Mapper.
- Provide the RecordReader implementation to be used to extract input records from the logical InputSplit for processing by the Mapper.

From the 1st point, one block is **not** exactly the input to the mapper; it is rather an `InputSplit`. e.g. think about a Zip File (compressed with `GZIP`). A Zip file is a collection of `ZipEntry` (each compressed file). A zip file is a non-splitable from processing perspective. It means, the `InputSplit` for a Zip file will be of several blocks (in fact all the blocks used to store the particular ZIP file). This happens at the expense of data locality. i.e. even though the zip file is broken and stored in `HDFS` at different node, the whole file would be moved to the node running the mapper.
The `ZipFileInputFormat` provides the default record reader implementation `ZipFileRecordReader`, which has logic to read one `ZipEntry` (compressed file) for the mapper key-value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the role of InputFormat? What is the relationship between InputFormat and RecordReader?

Comment: For a given block (assuming size of input split == block size), is InputFormat responsible to convert the chunk of "raw data" into records, and RecordReader is responsible for reading each record withing the block/input split, and converting each record to (key,value) pairs and passing them to mapper? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have added more details to the original post, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You've already basically answered this for yourself, so hopefully my explanation can help.

A record is a MapReduce-specific term for a key-value pair. A single MapReduce job can have several different types of records - in the wordcount example then the mapper input record type is `<Object, Text>`, the mapper output/reducer input record type is `<Text, IntWritable>`, and the reducer output record type is also `<Text, IntWritable>`.

The InputFormat is responsible for defining how the block is split into individual records. As you identified, there are many InputFormats, and each is responsible for implementing code that manages how it splits the data into records.

The block itself has no concept of records as the records aren't created until the data is read the mapper. You could have two separate MapReduce jobs that read the same block but use different InputFormats. As far as the HDFS is concerned, it's just storing a single big blob of data.

There's no "condition" for defining how the data is split - you can make your own InputFormat and split the data however you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Consider a case in which we are processing a binary data and we use TextFileInputFormat, how does this logic fit in? What would be considered as record? I am still not clear. I got the point that it is InputFormat which decides what is record, but some logic needs to be present there?

Comment: Well if you're reading binary data, you'd probably need to write your own InputFormat that understands the binary data and can split it into appropriate key/value pairs. The TextFileInputFormat wouldn't work in this situation.

Comment: So the definition of "record" depends solely on the InputFormat; and it converts a given block into records, which are fed to the mapper as (key, value)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.